# Specifying the return type when the output comes from a library with no type hints / stubs

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

When importing a library with missing stubs (no type hints), mypy flags it as a module with no stubs. An easy fix is to add `# type: ignore` after the import, however, all return types become `Any`. Now if I define a function that returns something coming out of this library, it seems that I would need to define the return type as `Any` as well.

This seems very generic and I would like to know if there's a more explicit way of defining the return type instead of having `Any` every time a library doesn't have stubs.

Here's a very simple example using Plotly:

```
import plotly.express as px # type: ignore
from plotly import graph_objects as go
from pandas import DataFrame

def plot_df(df: DataFrame) -> go.Figure:
    return px.bar(data_frame=df)
```

which triggers the following mypy error: "*error: Return type becomes "Any" due to an unfollowed import  [no-any-unimported]*". Replacing `go.Figure` with `Any` fixes the problem but, again, I'd like to know if there's a better way of doing this.

I am using Python 3.9.16 and here's the configuration of mypy in my pyproject.toml file:

```
[tool.mypy]
disallow_untyped_defs = true
disallow_any_unimported = true
no_implicit_optional = true
check_untyped_defs = true
warn_return_any = true
warn_unused_ignores = true
show_error_codes = true
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: What does it say the type is if you `print(type(the_thing))`

Comment: I think it's interesting that these IDE's can tell you everything that is wrong with your type but, can't simply determine the type for you. Maybe something like "type was List[int] but is now being used as List[int|float] update type?" and simply manage all types for you.

Comment: @OysterShucker for a given DataFrame `df`, ```print(type(plot_df(df)))``` outputs `<class 'plotly.graph_objs._figure.Figure'>`. Also if I verify the type with ```print(isinstance(plot_df(df), go.Figure))``` I have `True`

Comment: `plotly`'s root package is this: https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/tree/master/packages/python/plotly/plotly. In your local environment, generate a [blank `py.typed` file](https://peps.python.org/pep-0561/#packaging-type-information) at this location. If your code is put under CI, consider running the `py.typed` file generation step there as well.

Comment: You can check out [`--ignore-missing-imports`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/command_line.html#cmdoption-mypy-ignore-missing-imports).

Comment: Btw, they [started](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/1103) adding type hints, so `py.typed` absence is now a bug. Consider opening a ticket for that - they simply need to add a `py.typed` empty text file to the package root. I suppose they will be glad to accept a PR doing this, if you can afford contributing one.

Comment: thanks for the hint @STerliakov, will look into that

Answer (score -1):

You can use `typing.Cast` on the returned values of unmarked functions: that will tell the type of the value returned by the un-instrumented code as it reach yours, and the tooling will be able to follow from there.

One thing to *always* have in mind is that typing has NO run time effect in Python, the static typing tools essentially "see the code structure" in parallel to the execution - and `typing.cast`  itself has no runtime effect (although it is not "optimized out" of running code: a function call is made, even though on Python 3.11 and later that should be optmized enough)

```
from typing import cast

...

def plot_df(df: DataFrame) -> go.Figure:
    return cast(go.Figure, px.bar(data_frame=df))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However this still triggers errors:
'error: Return type becomes "Any" due to an unfollowed import  [no-any-unimported]' and 'error: Target type of cast becomes "Any" due to an unfollowed import  [no-any-unimported]'

Comment: That's not about `cast` at all: you can narrow `Any` by assignment to any type. Try `x: Any = 1; y: str = x` - you don't need a cast to assign `Any` to any variable, it's the whole point of `Any` - "top" type, which is assignable to everyting. The problem is that `go.Figure` **itself** is `Any` for `mypy` due to absent stubs (hence my downvote). See @dROOOze comment on the post for the possible solution. You need stubs or a way to tweak `mypy` to think that stubs are not needed - either `stubgen` or `py.typed`, resp.